# How to post multipartformdata in xamarin ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, multipartform-data

I'm developing mobile app for IOS using Xamarin IOS and when I try to post image to server using xamarin PostAsync() method, unfortunately it raises an exception.

```
public async Task<string> PostCreatePlatform(Platform new_platform, Byte[] image)
{
   new_platform.id = null;
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Token {0}", TokenInit.Token));
      var response = await client.PostAsync(b + "platforms/", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new_platform, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }).ToString(),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         if (image != null)
         {
            var TempPlatform = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Platform>(TempPlatform);
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            new_platform.id = final.id.Value;
            form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(image, 0, image.Count()), "file");
            var response2 = await client.PostAsync(String.Format(b + "platform/{0}/attachments/upload/", new_platform.id.Value), form);
            if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               return "success";
            }
         else
         {
            return "failed";
         }

         }
            return "success";
      }
      else
      {
         return "failed";
      }
 }
```

InnerException: System.ObjectDisposedException

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —-> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —-> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x000b2] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:616
at System.IO.Stream+<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs:729
at at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`3[System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult,System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]:invoke_TResult_T1_T2 (System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:1441
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447
at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent+<SerializeToStreamAsync>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00265] in <eadf07f9d3724ef0a06ee9064ef34579>:0
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x0031d] in <eadf07f9d3724ef0a06ee9064ef34579>:0
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__48.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <eadf07f9d3724ef0a06ee9064ef34579>:0
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
at FirstApp.ApiInteracting+<PostCreatePlatform>d__7.MoveNext () [0x003e2] in /Users/team1/Downloads/testiOSbayards2-6d24bc43fee6abd445ebcaea12b76c61649468a6/FirstApp/API/ApiInteracting.cs:176
—- End of inner exception stack trace —-
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:562
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:532
at FirstApp.AddPlatformTableViewController+<>c__DisplayClass247_0.<CreatePlatformButtonUpInside>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/team1/Downloads/testiOSbayards2-6d24bc43fee6abd445ebcaea12b76c61649468a6/FirstApp/UIClasses/AddPlatformTableViewController.cs:115
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
—- End of inner exception stack trace —-
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:562
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:532
at FirstApp.AddPlatformTableViewController+<>c__DisplayClass247_1.<CreatePlatformButtonUpInside>b__2 () [0x00001] in /Users/team1/Downloads/testiOSbayards2-6d24bc43fee6abd445ebcaea12b76c61649468a6/FirstApp/UIClasses/AddPlatformTableViewController.cs:119
at Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/3e5ac5ff/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:57
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/3e5ac5ff/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/3e5ac5ff/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
at FirstApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/team1/Downloads/testiOSbayards2-6d24bc43fee6abd445ebcaea12b76c61649468a6/FirstApp/Main.cs:12
```

Moreover, I reproduced this method using .NET C# compiler(not Mono) and manually with web debugging tool(Fiddler) and everything is ok.

**Update:**

The problem was resolved. Size of image was too big - 18mb.

Comment: please do NOT post code as images!!!!!!  Take the time post and format it as text.  Further, an AggregateException will contain an InnerExceptions collection with detail about what is actually causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. it works for me. Hope it helps.

```
 public class PostImageData
    {
        public int success { get; private set; }

    public async Task postData(string username, string password,string documentid, StreamContent streamContent)
    {
        UploadPhoto details = new UploadPhoto();
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uplod done");
            var clinet = new HttpClient();
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(streamContent, "file", "test.jpeg");
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage r =await clinet.PostAsync(YOUR_URL, content);                
            string json =await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadPhoto>(json);
            if (details.message == "Upload success")
            {
                success = 200;
            }
            success = 200;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            success = 400;
        }
    }
    public class UploadPhoto
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```